# select2 does not load ajax data: TypeError: c.ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Just by doing `Select2` *[hello-world](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)* exercises I cannot load `ajax` data, but rather getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: c.ajax is not a function
>      at Object.transport (select2.min.js:1)
>      at d (select2.min.js:1)

My code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-input').select2({
      placeholder: "Search for something",
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      ajax: {
        url: "https://www.example.com/search",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
          return {
            "term": params.term, // search term
            "from": 0,
            "size": 20
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          params.page = params.page || 1;
          data.hits = $.map(data.hits, function(obj) {
            obj.text = obj.text || obj.name;
            return obj;
          });
          return {
            results: data.hits,
          };
        },
        cache: true
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The underlying problem was in `jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js`, according to [some sources](https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/16/jquery-3-2-0-is-out/) `ajax` has been removed from the `slim` version of jquery, therefore to make `select2` work again one needs include full version of jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```